# How can I await task in Task<T> function?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I can't succeed to find the right way to do this:

```
public Task<List<HWElDocument>> GetHWElDocumentsAsync(int? ProjectID = null)
{
    // Get all Items
    if (ProjectID == null)
        return database.Table<HWElDocument>().ToListAsync();

    // Or all items meeting a condition
    else
    {
        // This line has to be awaited, I think ?!?
        List<HWDocuProj> projList = await database.Table<HWDocuProj>().Where( item => item.ProjID == ProjectID).ToListAsync();
        // So that I can use the result here:
        return database.Table<HWElDocument>().Where(item => projList.Exists(p => p.ProjID == item.ID)).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Because of the await keyword, the compiler ask to transform the function in an async function. But I do so, therefore it refuses that the result is a `Task<T'>` ... If I change the return type to `async List<HWElDocument'>`, then this line throws an error:

```
return database.Table<HWElDocument>().ToListAsync();
```

What is the correct way to achieve this then?

Comment: `public async Task<…`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I change the return type to `async List<HWElDocument'>`

You need *both* an `async` modifier on the method *and* a `Task` return type. So this signature should work:

```cs
public async Task<List<HWElDocument>> GetHWElDocumentsAsync(int? ProjectID = null)
```

The `async` will tell the compiler to internally use an asynchronous state machine and allows you to use the `await` keyword inside of the method.

And when you want to return something from an asynchronous method, you will need a `Task<T>` return type. When using `async`, the compiler also will make sure to wrap your return value in a task automatically, so you can just return the value directly.

So your returning line should *also* use `await` in order to await the task from `ToListAsync` and then the result will be automatically wrapped in your method’s result task:

```cs
public Task<List<HWElDocument>> GetHWElDocumentsAsync(int? ProjectID = null)
{
    // Get all Items
    if (ProjectID == null)
        return await database.Table<HWElDocument>().ToListAsync();

    // Or all items meeting a condition
    else
    {
        List<HWDocuProj> projList = await database.Table<HWDocuProj>()
            .Where( item => item.ProjID == ProjectID)
            .ToListAsync();
        return await database.Table<HWElDocument>()
            .Where(item => projList.Exists(p => p.ProjID == item.ID))
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: You say "When using async, the compiler also will make sure to wrap your return value in a task automatically, so you can just return the value directly."

So in the return .... line, the compiler await the result of ToListAsync and then re-encapsulate it in a Task ?!? Isn't that double work ?!?

Comment: Wrapping the value in a task is not the work itself. The task is just a representation of the work that is being executed. So your method returns a task *immediately* (without waiting for anything) but that task will only complete when the work inside your method eventually completes. Similarly, the “awaiting” also isn’t work because you are explicitly telling the runtime to do something else in between and only continue working when the task (which represents the actual work) is completed. That’s the whole point with async/await, that you are not keeping things busy while waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to "await" an async function whenever you call it. You can do so by simply putting the "await" keyword at the start:

```
return await database.Table<HWElDocument>().Where(item => projList.Exists(p => p.ProjID == item.ID)).ToListAsync();
```

and

```
return await database.Table<HWElDocument>().ToListAsync();
```

You also need "async" in your method signature:

```
public async Task<List<HWElDocument>> GetHWElDocumentsAsync(int? ProjectID = null)
```

Microsoft has a more detailed guide on asynchronous programming in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Um, you don't _need to await an async function whenever you call it_. You can (and you usually do), or you can call several of them and `await WhenAny` or `await WhenAll`. There are other calling patterns as well